# Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

Hello guys write my first hibernate code and have some problem please help. Show the code and Error

input Error

```
    Exception in thread "main" 2017-03-11 21:53:11 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: permission denied for relation employee
2017-03-11 21:53:11 [main] INFO  o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2017-03-11 21:53:11 [main] ERROR o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:224)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:755)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:594)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at ua.goit.java.jdbc.model.controllers.EmployeeController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f052d1ce.creatEmploee(<generated>)
    at ua.goit.java.jdbc.Main.start(Main.java:19)
    at ua.goit.java.jdbc.Main.main(Main.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3003)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3503)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:586)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1428)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:582)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for relation employee
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2125)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:297)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:136)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:410)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
    ... 33 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

class Employee

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "position")
    private Position position;
    @Column(name = "salary")
    private Float salary;


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPosition(Position position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void setSalary(Float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

class HEmployeeDao

```
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import ua.goit.java.jdbc.model.Employee;
import ua.goit.java.jdbc.model.EmployeeDao;

import java.util.List;

public class HEmployeeDao implements EmployeeDao{

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     @Transactional
    public void save(Employee employee) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(employee);
    }

       public Employee load(Long id) {
        return null;
    }

    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

class EmployeeControler

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import ua.goit.java.jdbc.model.Employee;
import ua.goit.java.jdbc.model.Position;
import ua.goit.java.jdbc.model.hibernate.HEmployeeDao;

public class EmployeeController {
    private HEmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @Transactional
    public void creatEmploee(){
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(1L);
        employee.setName("Alex");
        employee.setSurname("Kruglov");
        employee.setPhoneNumber("032-567-84");
        employee.setPosition(Position.WAITER);
        employee.setSalary(1000.00F);

        employeeDao.save(employee);
    }

    public void setEmployeeDao(HEmployeeDao employeeDao) {
        this.employeeDao = employeeDao;
    }
}
```

class Main

```
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import ua.goit.java.jdbc.model.controllers.EmployeeController;

public class Main {

    private EmployeeController employeeController;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("aplication-context.xml", "hibernate-context.xml");
        Main main = applicationContext.getBean(Main.class);
        main.start();
    }

    private void start() {
        employeeController.creatEmploee();
    }

    public void setEmployeeController(EmployeeController employeeController) {
        this.employeeController = employeeController;
    }
}
```

Maven pom.xml

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hibernatePractick</groupId>
    <artifactId>goit</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.0.0.jre7</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>


</project>
```

aplication-context.xm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

        <bean id="main" class="ua.goit.java.jdbc.Main">
            <property name="employeeController" ref="employeeController"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="employeeController" class="ua.goit.java.jdbc.model.controllers.EmployeeController">
            <property name="employeeDao" ref="employeeDao"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="employeeDao" class="ua.goit.java.jdbc.model.hibernate.HEmployeeDao">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

hibernate-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManeger" proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
    </bean>


    <bean class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driver.class}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.min.connections}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.max.connections}"/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${jdbc.acquire.increment}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="ua.goit.java.jdbc.model"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <value>
                    hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
                </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManeger" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

jdbc.propetries

```
jdbc.driver.class=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/restaurant
jdbc.user=user
jdbc.password=1111
jdbc.max.connections=10
jdbc.min.connections=1
jdbc.acquire.increment=1
```

Comment: Have you read the error? It says: "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for relation employee". So, the user that you uses to connect to the PostgreSQL database through Hibernate doesn't have the permission to write to the employee table. Fix the permissions. All the code you posted is completely irrelevant. Your very first step when getting an error is to read it.

Comment: Thenks a lot, it's WORKING .

Comment: I try to read , but my English isn't wery good. But I learn :)